# swift: сделать, чтобы исчезнувшие объекты один раз появились в количестве от 1 до 3 (рандомно)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, insert, append

Вот кусок кода, где из массива `items` берется от 1 до 3 элементов (всего их 21). Мне надо сделать, чтобы один раз при нажатии на элемент он не исчез, а появились (из тех, которые уже были взяты) от 1 до 3 (рандомно).

```
@IBOutlet var items: [UIButton]!
@IBAction func itemsHidden(sender: UIButton!) {

    if items.count > 0 && aiDeciding == false {
        if moveCount < 3 {
            sender.hidden = true
            if let index = items.indexOf(sender) {
                items.removeAtIndex(index)

              //вот что я пробовал
               let numberToInsert = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3))) 

                for _ in 0..<numberToInsert {

                    let tag = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count)))
                    items[tag].hidden = false
                    items.append(tag)
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Еще раз, что вам надо сделать?

Comment: Пример: начинаем игру. я беру 2 элемента, соперник берет 3, я один и т.д. НО! в один из моментов (который определяется рандомно) при нажатии на элемент, он не исчезает, а наоборот, из тех, которые уже были взяты, появились бы в количестве от 1 до 3-х (рандомно).

Comment: вам надо создать массив и в него складывать все элементы, которые уже были взяты. когда происходит нажатие на кнопку, использовать рандом `arc4random_uniform(x)` и если нужное вам значение пришло, то опять же используя рандом выбирать сколько элементов вы хотите, чтобы появилось, и их показывать. Другими словами вы очень много бизнес логики хотите написать. попробуйте как то конкретизировать вопрос, если у вас что то конкретное не получается.

Comment: добавил кусок кода, который я пробовал. Но он некорректный. Где там ошибка, не пойму...

Comment: в вашем коде, вы выбираете случайный объект из массива и делаете его видимым, то есть скорее всего вы просто наткнетесь на объект, который и так видимый и все.

Comment: Да. Именно в этом проблемка. Мне надо изменить let tag = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count)))?!

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не думаю, что такой ответ устроит спрашивающего.

Comment: Почему не устроит?!

Answer (score 1):

вам надо создать массив и в него складывать все элементы, которые уже были взяты. Когда происходит нажатие на кнопку, использовать рандом `arc4random_uniform(x)` и если нужное вам значение пришло, то опять же используя рандом выбирать сколько элементов вы хотите, чтобы появилось, и их показывать.